# How to get R to read a gdb file?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf, rgdal

I am trying to get R to read in a gdb file. First thing I did was to find out its layers, which I did by running:

```
ogrListLayers("my_data.gdb")
```

It turns to out my_data has two large layers. I have tried opening both but have had no success. Here is what I have tried so far:

1)

```
Wont_open <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/my_data.gdb", layer =  "layer_1", dropNULLGeometries = F)
```

I have tried the above with and without the dropNULLGeometries argument and for both layers in my_data. When running this, I get the following error:

```
Error in readOGR(dsn = "D:/my_data.gdb",  : 
Unsupported field type: Binary
```

2. Wont_open <- st_read(dsn="D:/my_data.gdb", layer =  "layer_1")

I have tried the above for both layers in my_data. When I run this, R simply stops working after about 1 hour of having started the process.

3)

```
read_GDB_Layer <- function(dsn, layerName, overwrite = T){
conversionDir <- tempdir() 

gdalUtils:: ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name = dsn, dst_datasource_name = conversionDir, f = "ESRI Shapefile", layer + layerName, verbose = T, overwrite = overwrite) 

df <- read.dbf(file.path(conversionDir, paste0(layerName, ".gdbtable"))) 

return(df)}
```

Then,

```
Wont_open <- read_GDB_Layer(dsn = "D:/my_data.gdb", layerName = "layer_1")
```

I tried this for both layers and changed the .gdbtable argument of the function for .dbf to run it on both layers and it still did not work. I got the following warning messages:

```
1: In gdal_setInstallation(search_path = NULL, rescan = FALSE, ignore.full_scan = TRUE,  :
  No GDAL installation found. Please install 'gdal' before continuing:
    - www.gdal.org (no HDF4 support!)
    - trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (with HDF4 support RECOMMENDED)
    - www.fwtools.maptools.org (with HDF4 support)

2: In gdal_setInstallation(search_path = NULL, rescan = FALSE, ignore.full_scan = TRUE,  :
  If you think GDAL is installed, please run:
gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi @Sven Brandt. Would it be possible to have your .gdb file (or an excerpt) to do some tests?

Comment: Hi @lovalery! Thanks for connecting with me over this issue. I forgot to post an update. It turns out the st_read() function was actually able to open it. The original dataset was too large, so I had to speak with my friend to use his ArcGIS Pro to segregate the portion of the data that I needed. This data goes back to 1916, but I only needed from 2020 onward. Once I segregated that part of the data, I was able to open it using st_read().

Comment: Hi @Sven Brandt. Thank you very much for your feedback and glad to hear that you have managed to solve your problem. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`terra::vect()` can be used to open the spatial features in .gdb as well. I'm not sure if this function handles large files any more efficiently or not, but it seems like it might be worth trying.

One benefit of `terra::vect()` is that you call can utilize the `proxy` parameter which keeps the data on disk rather than memory. From there you can you the `terra::query()` function to subset your object and produce a vect object. This seems like a reasonable means of reducing the total size of the object.

[docs for query function](https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/query.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `st_read()` function worked for me, as pointed by @sven-brandt